# Conditional check if Matrix block field is empty (no content)

Tags: matrix, entry, conditional

I'm having a difficult time with what seems like a fairly straightforward problem:

I'm listing businesses and their related hours of operation (days/times). I'd like to set up a conditional statement that checks if a Matrix field has content—if so, display hours. If not, display message. My code is as follows:

```
{% if entry.hours.block('days')|length %} <!-- I am trying to check Matrix field "days" is empty (content exists) -->
<div class="entry__hours">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      {% for block in entry.hours %}<!-- Loop through days/times...this part works fine -->
      <tr>
        <td class="entry__days">{{ block.days }}</td>
        <td class="entry__times">{{ block.times }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% else %} <!-- This part does not show up if Matrix field "days" is empty -->
  <p>We're still trying to track down hours.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I've also attached a screenshot of my Matrix setup. Thanks so much in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cQ5z.png)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your matrix field is not called hours? Because in your current code you are handeling it like it is.

I think this should work

```
   {% for block in entry.matrixfieldHandle %}
       {% if block|length %}
           {{block.days}} - {{block.time}}
       {% else %}
           <p>Do something else</p>
       {% endif% }
    {% endfor %}
```

In your code you want to loop over all the different entries (blocks) within the matrix. If you want to add other types you can easely check for hours like so:

```
{% if block.type == "hours" %}
   do stuff
{% elseif block.type == "anotherblocktype" %}
   ...
```

However. Since you only use one type of content I'm not sure if a matrix is the best solution. You could easely put this in a table or [supertable](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) .

Then you could just do

```
{% for row in entry.tableHandle %}
   {% if row|length %}
       {{row.text}}
   {% else % }
       <p>Fallback</p>
{% endif %}
```

Another option is to check this little plugin: [Store hours](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/StoreHours)

Comment: Thanks so much Jan! Your suggestions worked like a charm—however, you're correct that a matrix was not the best solution. I'd simply gotten so used to using it, I forgot about all my other options. A table worked great and simplified things quite a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: You can always mark my answer as correct @Adam ;-)